# Unable to set autoflash on android Camera object

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm running an app that use surfaceView for show Camera object output, and i need to set automatic flash when take picture. I thought that it could be a simple thing, but i was wrong!
This is my code:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size result = getBestPreviewSize(params, width, height);
    params.setPreviewSize(result.width, result.height);
    params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    params.setJpegQuality(100);
    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
    params.setPictureSize(dpWidth, dpWidth);
    params.setRotation(90);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);

    mCamera.startPreview();

}
```

and manifest has correct permission. When i launch my code, this is the error:

```
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901): Process: it.giozh.app, PID: 19901
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1651)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at it.ictinnova.hipstamemostylist.ScattaFoto.surfaceChanged(TakePic.java:144)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:583)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1867)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-17 13:54:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(19901):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing wrong from your coding point of view. Its vendor specific issue. In some devices set parameters works in some does not. The solution i found to over come with it is put below line of code in try catch block. I would also suggest please check which parameters camera is not allowing you to set by try one by one all params that you want to set. For me it was failing for set height and width.

`mCamera.setParameters(params);`

**check have you set these features in manifest**

`android.hardware.camera.autofocus`

`android.hardware.camera.flash`

if any other alternamte solution found please add comment.

Comment: I don't need to catch exception, because my app should run only on a specific device (in my case a nexus 7) so i'm search a way to make autoflash only on it!

EDIT. In my case the only parameter that cause crash is FALSH_MODE_AUTO. If i comment that line, everithing works

Comment: Ya still but things what i found its works set params works on some devices not all. Try settings params one by one

Comment: @giozh the Nexus 7 doesn't even have a camera flash light if I remember?

Comment: Yes, it don't have it, my fault! I've try my code in advice on a device with flashlight, so when i put it on nexus 7 i don't think about flash abscence. 
In fact, if i call params.getSupportedFlashModes(), only off mode appear ! Thanks for your answer